# How does one refactor best this timer/stopwatch code-base towards a better code-reuse following the OOP paradigm and the DRY principle?

Tags: javascript, oop, refactoring, dry, code-reuse

I am having trouble with following **OOP** in javascript.
How can I make this code more **Object-oriented** and reusable?

I tried reading up on OOP concepts in JS but couldn't figure a way around making this code be one. *Any suggestions?*

**PS: This is the code for making a stopwatch**

```
//Define variables to hold time values
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

//Define variable to  hold "display" value
let interval = null;

//Define variable to hold the clock status
let status = "paused";

//Clock function ( logic to determine when to increment next value, etc.)
function clock() {
  seconds++;

  //Logic to determine when to increment next value
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  //Display updated time values to user
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
    //If seconds/minutes/hours are only one digit, add a leading 0 to the value
    `${hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : `0${hours}`) : "00"}:${minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : `0${minutes}`) : "00"}:${seconds > 9 ? seconds : `0${seconds}`}`;
}

function startPause() {
  if (status === "paused") {
    //Start the stopwatch (by calling the setInterval() function)
    interval = window.setInterval(clock, 1000);
    document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Pause";
    status = "started";
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Resume";
    status = "paused";
  }
}

//Function to reset the stopwatch
function reset() {
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
  document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start";
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  status = "paused";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use kind of a *"component based"* approach. The provided example code is pretty straightforward. The constructor does assign all the needed references as public properties to a `Stopwatch` instance. Getters and setters for reading and writing the component's UI(/DOM) part are implemented as prototypal methods. Helper methods (interval handling, time measure computations) do not need to be part of the class implementation itself, but will be residents of the `Stopwatch` module scope ...

```js
// module scope of e.g. 'Stopwatch.js' file.

const MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING = 'running';
const MEASURE_STATE_STOPPED = 'stopped';

const UPDATE_CYCLE_MINIMUM = 100;   // any value in msec.
const UPDATE_CYCLE_DEFAULT = 200;   //
const UPDATE_CYCLE_MAXIMUM = 1000;  //

function getDisplayNumber(value) {
  return ((String(value).length === 1) && `0${ value }`) || value;
}

function getMeasureInMilliseconds(measure) {
  return (((measure.hours * 3600) + (measure.minutes * 60) + measure.seconds) * 1000);
}
function getMeasureFromMilliseconds(value) {
  let hours = (value / 3600000);
  let minutes = ((hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60);
  let seconds = ((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60);

  hours = Math.floor(hours);
  minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  seconds = Math.floor(seconds + 0.001);

  seconds = ((seconds < 60) && seconds) || 0;
  minutes = ((minutes < 60) && minutes) || 0;
  hours = ((hours < 100) && hours) || 0;

  return { hours, minutes, seconds };
}

function handleStartStopForBoundStopwatch(/* evt */) {
  const stopwatch = this;
  if (stopwatch.measureState === MEASURE_STATE_STOPPED) {

    stopwatch.startMeasure();
  } else {
    stopwatch.stopMeasure();
  }
}

function updateStopwatchMeasure(stopwatch) {
  const dateNow = Date.now();

  // has at least one second past since the last measure update?
  const isUpdateMeasure = (Math.floor((dateNow - stopwatch.updateTimestamp) / 1000) >= 1);

  if (isUpdateMeasure) {
    stopwatch.updateTimestamp = dateNow;

    // time differences in milliseconds since measuring has been started the last time.
    const timePassed = (dateNow - stopwatch.measureTimestamp);
    const messureValue = (timePassed + stopwatch.lastMeasuredMSecs);

    Object.assign(stopwatch.measure, getMeasureFromMilliseconds(messureValue));

    stopwatch.setComponentMeasure();
  }
}


class Stopwatch {

  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    this.timerId = null;
    this.updateCycle = this.getComponentUpdateCycle();

    // for synchronizing display values of a running measure.
    this.lastMeasuredMSecs = null;
    this.measureTimestamp = null;
    this.updateTimestamp = null;

    this.measure = this.getComponentMeasure();
    this.measureState = this.getComponentMeasureState();

    // synchronize component data initially.
    this.setComponentMeasure();
    this.setComponentMeasureState();

    if (this.measureState === MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING) {
      this.startMeasure();
    }
    this.startStopHandler = handleStartStopForBoundStopwatch.bind(this);

    node.addEventListener('click', this.startStopHandler);
  }
  destroy() {
    if (this.node) {
      this.node.removeEventListener('click', this.startStopHandler);
      this.node.remove();
      this.node = null;
      delete this.node;
    }
    this.timerId = this.updateCycle = this.lastMeasuredMSecs = null;
    this.measureTimestamp = this.updateTimestamp = null;
    this.measure = this.measureState = this.startStopHandler = null;

    delete this.timerId;
    delete this.updateCycle;
    delete this.lastMeasuredMSecs;
    delete this.measureTimestamp;
    delete this.updateTimestamp;
    delete this.measure;
    delete this.measureState;
    delete this.startStopHandler;
  }

  getComponentMeasure() {
    const result =
      (/^(?<hours>\d{1,2})\:(?<minutes>\d{1,2})\:(?<seconds>\d{1,2})$/)
      .exec(
        this.node.dateTime
      );
    const {
      hours,
      minutes,
      seconds
    } = (result && result.groups) || { hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 };

    return {
      hours: parseInt(hours, 10),
      minutes: parseInt(minutes, 10),
      seconds: parseInt(seconds, 10)
    };
  }
  setComponentMeasure() {
    const { hours, minutes, seconds } = this.measure;
    const value = [
      getDisplayNumber(hours),
      getDisplayNumber(minutes),
      getDisplayNumber(seconds)
    ].join(':');

    this.node.dateTime = value;
    this.node.innerText = value;
  }

  getComponentMeasureState() {
    return (
      ((this.node.dataset.measureState || '').trim() === 'running')
      && MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING
      || MEASURE_STATE_STOPPED
    );
  }
  setComponentMeasureState() {
    this.node.dataset.measureState = this.measureState;

    if (this.measureState === MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING) {

      this.node.classList.add(MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING);
      this.node.classList.remove(MEASURE_STATE_STOPPED);
    } else {
      this.node.classList.add(MEASURE_STATE_STOPPED);
      this.node.classList.remove(MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING);
    }
  }

  getComponentUpdateCycle() {
    let value = parseInt(this.node.dataset.updateCycle, 10);
    value = (Number.isNaN(value) && UPDATE_CYCLE_DEFAULT) || value;
    return Math.max(UPDATE_CYCLE_MINIMUM, Math.min(UPDATE_CYCLE_MAXIMUM, value));
  }

  startMeasure() {
    this.measureTimestamp = this.updateTimestamp = Date.now();
    this.lastMeasuredMSecs = getMeasureInMilliseconds(this.measure);

    this.timerId = setInterval(

      updateStopwatchMeasure,
      this.updateCycle,
      this
    );
    this.measureState = MEASURE_STATE_RUNNING;
    this.setComponentMeasureState();
  }
  stopMeasure() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);

    this.lastMeasuredMSecs = null;
    this.measureTimestamp = null;
    this.updateTimestamp = null;

    this.measureState = MEASURE_STATE_STOPPED;
    this.setComponentMeasureState();
  }/*
  resetMeasure() {
    Object.assign(this.measure, {
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 0
    });
    this.setComponentMeasure();
  }*/

  static initialize(node) {
    return new Stopwatch(node);
  }
}


/*export default*/function initialize() {
  return Array
    .from(document.body.querySelectorAll('.stopwatch-component'))
    .map(Stopwatch.initialize);
}


/**
 *  usage
 */
const timerList = initialize();

// console.log('timerList :', timerList);
```

```css
dd {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.stopwatch-component {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: x-large;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stopwatch-component.stopped {
  text-decoration: line-through solid #999;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>
    1st time measurement
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <time
      class="stopwatch-component"
      datetime="0:0:0"
      data-update-cycle="100"
      data-measure-state="running">0:0:0</time>
  </dd>
  <dt>
    2nd time measurement
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <time
      class="stopwatch-component"
      datetime="99:59:33"
      data-update-cycle="1000">99:59:33</time>
  </dd>
  <dt>
    3rd time measurement
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <time
      class="stopwatch-component"
      datetime="07:11:55"
      data-update-cycle="500"
      data-measure-state="stopped">7:11:55</time>
  </dd>
</dl>
<p>Click each time measure separately for toggling its pause/proceed state.</p>
```

***Note:***

In order to keep the (re)rendering of seconds (minutes, hours) that have been passed in sync, one needs another timer approach than the one provided by the OP.

The examples run with different configurable update cycles defined by the value of the `data-update-cycle` attribute of a `<time class="stopwatch-component"/>` element. An update interval of 500msec or just 1sec is not suitable for this kind of measure task, due to `setInterval` being not precise enough. The running example does demonstrate exactly that.

One has to keep the displayed data in sync by constantly comparing the timestamp from starting a measure process with the timestamp from the current update process. The (re)rendering of a displayed value of cause takes place only if at least a second has passed since the last (re)rendering. But the update cycles which constantly (but not permanently) triggers the (re)rendering has to be run at a higher frequency.

Comment: @Roshin ... are there any still not answered question?