# JavaScript stopwatch being slower than expected

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, stopwatch, milliseconds

In my quest to become a JavaScript developer and as an F1 fan, I had to make a stopwatch, to track reaction time. The problem I stumbled upon, and it seems to be the case in many tutorials I've seen, is that you can't really be millisecond exact.

What I mean is, when I try to set an Interval for every 10 milliseconds, it works perfectly, but if I try to set an Interval for **1 millisecond, 1 second on my page is like 5 seconds** in real life.

```js
let clock = document.querySelector('.timer')
let interval = null;
let milliseconds = 0;
let seconds =0;



window.addEventListener('click', () => {
        interval = setInterval(startClock,10)
})


document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            alert(`${seconds}:${milliseconds}`);
        },50) 
    }
})

function startClock(){
    milliseconds += 10;
    if(milliseconds==1000){
        milliseconds = 0;
        seconds++;
    }

    let sec = seconds.toString();
    let ms = milliseconds.toString();
    if(seconds<10){
        sec = `0${seconds}`;
    }

    if(milliseconds<100){
        ms = `0${milliseconds}`;
    }

    clock.innerHTML =`${sec}:${ms}`;
}
```

```css
p{
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    font-size: 170px;
    height: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="timer">00:000</p>
```

Comment: Javascript engines don't a delay of 1ms, and they never have. Historically, browsers enforced a minimum of anywhere from 4 to 16ms. Today the spec only mentions a minimum in the context of nested timeouts, but the fact is still that no JS runtime will give you 1ms. MDN documents [some reasons timeouts may take longer than you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers) also says "does not guarantee that timers will run exactly on schedule".

Comment: The OP also might read the explanation under _**Note**_ of the answer to following question ... [_"How does one refactor best this timer/stopwatch code-base towards a better code-reuse following the OOP paradigm and the DRY principle?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976801/how-does-one-refactor-best-this-timer-stopwatch-code-base-towards-a-better-code/63982638#63982638)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't guarantee how long the code inside the interval will take to run, it's better to use the `Date` api. Instead of relying on the interval, you could run a loop that constantly calculates the ms between now and the start.

Here's an example of this concept:

```js
// assume this runs when the stopwatch starts
let startTime = new Date().getTime()

// this should stop when the user stops the timer, but I'm using a for loop
// for the example
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let now = new Date().getTime()
  console.log("ms elapsed: " + (now - startTime))
}
```

Now it doesn't matter how fast the code is; it should always be accurate.

Comment: Yes, that might be the best way, i saw a codepen that used date, i will try to experiment with that, thank you

Answer (score 3):

> for every 10 milliseconds, it works perfect

Even then it's not reliable.  It can drift over time, it can be delayed by anything blocking the UI even for the briefest of moments, etc.

Taking a step back... Do you really *need* your UI clock to display every individual millisecond?  Are you observing the results 1,000 times per second?  Motion pictures update a couple dozen times per second and we perceive them as fluid continuous motion.  What *human* needs to see 1,000 distinct numbers per second?

Instead, have your clock update the UI at regular intervals (if every 10ms is working for you then that's reasonable, every 50ms would probably be reasonable too) to show the current time.  You don't need to create a stopwatch to measure time, the computer is already measuring time and you can query that measurement whenever you like, as often as you like.

All your "stopwatch" needs to do is know when it started and it can always calculate the elapsed milliseconds since then.

You can perhaps try to *mimic* the more random look and feel of a quickly-ticking millisecond timer by making the intervals an odd number, like 27ms or 41ms.

For example:

```js
let clock = document.querySelector('.timer')
let interval = null;
let startTime = null;

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  startTime = new Date();
  interval = setInterval(clockTick, 42)
})

function clockTick(){
  let diff = new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime();
  clock.innerHTML =`${Math.floor(diff / 1000)}:${`${diff % 1000}`.padStart(3, "0")}`;
}
```

```css
p{
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    font-size: 170px;
    height: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="timer">00:000</p>
```

Comment: I mean for the project i am working on, you do really need to be precise,even with milliseconds, but you have a very valid point, about updating the UI, that seems to be the way to go,as far as the looks and keeping the result for the end. Date seems the way to go, for sure

Comment: @DimitrisS: Is there a loss of precision in this approach though?  At what point do you need to observe the current total time since starting?  Perhaps when a stop button is clicked?  At that time you can still measure the difference between when the timer began and the current time.

Comment: Yeah you are right, you can just get the time with Date and be done easily

Comment: Why not use `requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single-threaded, which means it can only run one task at a time, blocking everything else.

That's why the browser stops working if you do `while(true) {}`. You can't scroll, click, and all animations stop while the loop runs.

Instead, I would suggest to use `requestForAnimationFrame`, so the timer only updates when the screen does a repaint (60, 120, 144 or whatever Hz your monitor has).

My timer stops when you click a second time.

```js
const timerEl = document.getElementById('timer');
var startTime = 0, animationId = 0;

const toggleTimer = () => {
  if (startTime == 0) {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    startTimer();
  } else {
    stopTimer();
    updateTimerElement(new Date().getTime());
    startTime = 0;
  }
}

const startTimer = () => {
  updateTimerElement(new Date().getTime());
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(startTimer);
}

const stopTimer = () => {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
}

const updateTimerElement = (currentTime) => {
  let passedTime = currentTime - startTime;
  const MINUTE = 1000 * 60;
  const SECOND = 1000;
  
  let min = Math.floor(passedTime / MINUTE);
  
  passedTime = passedTime - min * MINUTE;

  let sec = Math.floor(passedTime / SECOND);
  
  let ms = passedTime - sec * SECOND;
    
  timerEl.innerText = `${addPadding(min)}:${addPadding(sec)}:${addPadding(ms, 3)}`;
}

const addPadding = (number, pad = 2) => {
  return String(number).padStart(pad, '0');
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { toggleTimer() })
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
}

#timer {
  font-size: 40vh;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">00:00:000</div>
```