# Creating a timer - Input value won't count down

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a countdown timer which starts counting down from a user defined value when a particular button is clicked. I can create a timer that counts down in a separate element, however that's not what I'm looking for.

I want the user inputted value to be the timer, and countdown to zero from there. However, I just can't get the user inputted value to count down at all.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Timer App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="appTitle">TIMER</h1>

  <div id="appContainer">
    <div class="timeContainer">
        <input id="hours" type="number" value = "0"></input>
            <span>:</span>
        <input id="mins" type="number" value = "0"></input>
            <span>:</span>
        <input id="secs" type="number" value = "0"></input>
    </div>


    <div class="btnContainer">
        <button id="startBtn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
var hoursInput = document.getElementById("hours")
var minsInput = document.getElementById("mins")
var secsInput = document.getElementById("secs")

var hours = hoursInput.InnerHTML = 0;
var minutes = minsInput.InnerHTML = 0;
var seconds = secsInput.InnerHTML = 0;

function startTimer() {
    hours = hoursInput.value;
    minutes = minutesInput.value;
    seconds = secondsInput.value;

    setInterval(function() {
        if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval();
            hoursInput.innerHTML = " ";
            minsInput.innerHTML = "TIME OUT";
            secsInput.innerHTML = " ";
        } else if (seconds == 0) {
            if (minutes == 0) {
                hours--;
                minutes = 59;
                seconds = 59;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 59;
            }
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You are never setting a new value for your inputs, execpt when you reach `0:00:00` And you shouldn't set the `input`'s value by `theinput.innerHTML = ...` but `theinput.value = ...`

Comment: And assuming this script is part of `script.js` it won't work anyways, because `hoursInput`, `minsInput` and `secsInput` will be undefined because the script is executed before those HTML elements are rendered. Put your script in the end of your HTML file ...

Comment: The chosen approach of counting seconds down by an interval based on exactly 1 second is anyhow not reliable or error prone, due to the interval not clocking precisely. A reliable approach needs to be based on an interval based on not more than 100 milliseconds which each time compares the current time with a start time reference value and renders the passed single second only when needed.

Comment: ... as for instance demonstrated at ... [How does one refactor best this timer/stopwatch code-base towards a better code-reuse following the OOP paradigm and the DRY principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976801/how-does-one-refactor-best-this-timer-stopwatch-code-base-towards-a-better-code)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You never return a value in your function : (note that you can run your code in snippet with SO, as is this below)

```js
var hoursInput = document.getElementById("hours");
var minsInput = document.getElementById("mins");
var secsInput = document.getElementById("secs");

var hours = (hoursInput.value = 0);
var minutes = (minsInput.value = 0);
var seconds = (secsInput.value = 0);
var intervalId;

function startTimer() {
  hours = hoursInput.value;
  minutes = minsInput.value;
  seconds = secsInput.value;

  intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      hoursInput.value = " ";
      minsInput.value = "TIME OUT";
      secsInput.value = " ";
    } else if (seconds == 0) {
      if (minutes == 0) {
        hours--;
        minutes = 59;
        seconds = 59;
      } else {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
      }
    } else {
      seconds--;
    }
    hoursInput.value = hours;
    minsInput.value = minutes;
    secsInput.value = seconds;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Timer App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="appTitle">TIMER</h1>

    <div id="appContainer">
      <div class="timeContainer">
        <input id="hours" type="number" value="0"></input>
        <span>:</span>
        <input id="mins" type="number" value="0"></input>
        <span>:</span>
        <input id="secs" type="number" value="0"></input>
      </div>

      <div class="btnContainer">
        <button id="startBtn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help on this one. This solution makes complete sense and works well.

Comment: @HarryC no problem, my pleasure. Don't forget to accept an answer to close the question

Answer (score -1):

I have changed `innerHTML` to `value`
and also declared variable name and used variable name is different corrected it with
`minutesInput` to  `minsInput` and `secondsInput` to `secsInput`

also added a paragraph to display the count-down and limited the input number

```js
var hoursInput = document.getElementById("hours")
var minsInput = document.getElementById("mins")
var secsInput = document.getElementById("secs")
var msg = document.getElementById("msg")


var hours = hoursInput.value = 0;
var minutes = minsInput.value = 0;
var seconds = secsInput.value = 0;

function startTimer() {
  hours = hoursInput.value;
  minutes = minsInput.value;
  seconds = secsInput.value;
  msg.innerHTML = ''

  setInterval(function() {
    if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval();
      msg.innerHTML = 'Time Out'
    } else if (seconds == 0) {
      if (minutes == 0) {
        hours--;
        minutes = 59;
        seconds = 59;
        msg.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
      } else {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
        msg.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds

      }
    } else {
      seconds--;
      msg.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Timer App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="appTitle">TIMER</h1>

    <div id="appContainer">
      <div class="timeContainer">
        <input id="hours" type="number" min="0" max="23" value="0"></input>
        <span>:</span>
        <input id="mins" type="number" min="0" max="59" value="0"></input>
        <span>:</span>
        <input id="secs" type="number" min="0" max="59" value="0"></input>
      </div>
      <br>


      <div class="btnContainer">
        <button id="startBtn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p id='msg'>
        <p>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Please add details to explain how you solved the problem

Comment: I added explanation to the solution @Johan

Answer (score -1):

When you call the function, you're not getting the values of the `input` tags at all.
You only called them once, when the page was loaded.
You should put them inside the function.
Then display the value before the timer loops again.
Also, I fixed and simplified the logic coz I found some flaws.

```
function startTimer() {
    let hoursInput   = document.getElementById("hours")
    let minutesInput = document.getElementById("mins")
    let secondsInput = document.getElementById("secs")

    let hours   = hoursInput.value
    let minutes = minutesInput.value
    let seconds = secondsInput.value
    
    // I changed your logic here coz it has problems -> mins running instead of sec
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            console.log("TIME OUT");
            clearInterval(timer); // PUT THE setInterval INTO A VARIABLE SO YOU CAN USE clearInterval
        }
        else if (seconds - 1 < 0) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes = hours == 0 && minutes == 0 ? 0 : (minutes - 1 < 0 ? 59 : minutes - 1)
            hours   = hours - 1 < 0 ? 0 : (minutes == 59 ? hours - 1 : hours)
        }
        else seconds--;
        
        // DISPLAY NEW VALUES
        hoursInput.value   = hours
        minutesInput.value = minutes
        secondsInput.value = seconds

    }, 1000); // 1000 == 1 second
}
```